# Unit tests in pycharm are running twice

Tags: pycharm, python-unittest

I need to generate a test report using HTMLTestRunner ,for that code (which is placed at the end of the file) is:

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestLoginPages)

outfile = open("/home/xxx/xxx/xxxx/report.html", "w")
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
    stream=outfile,
    title='Test Report',
    description='Test report for the application')
runner.run(suite)
```

Then I run the test cases from pycharm ,all the tests are running twice.
I have tried to 'Edit Configurations' in the 'Run' menu where I delete the  'unittest in my_file_name' configuration, but issue remains same

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: @PatK , sadly no, When I have to generate a test report I run the test cases from terminal not pycharm

Comment: I ran into a case where this was caused by a unit test file that had a relative import of something in a different unit test file in the same directory: `from .other_test import ...` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your manage.py file contains

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

PyCharm tries to make import of manage.py file to be sure there are no import errors. If your manage.py file does not contain **name** == "**main**" validation, then tests run on import stage as if they were launched from the bash and then PyCharm runs them directly once more.

Comment: Perfect!  I just ran into this with PyCharm 2017.2.3 and your solution resolved the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Tried

- Restarting Couple of times
- Reinstalling entire eco system
- Re-cloning of project

But didn't work

**Solution:** What worked for me
***Pycharm: Setting -> Project-> Project Interpreter***

It should not contain more than 1 runner of your test runner

In my case I had ***behave and behave-parallel*** I removed ***behave-parallel*** and every thing become normal.

I hope this will help you.